# Counting non-empty columns in a file

Tags: grep

I have a huge tab delimited file containing ID's like this,

```
Q8H1E4  C5XVC0

        M7ZVB2
Q0J032

Q8H1E4  M0Z0D4

C4J6K5
```

How to count # of ID's, without empty spaces in each column quickly, using bash command may be? so that it gives me 4 for column 1 and 3 for column 3. Also how to count unique ID's, since the same ID might appear several times in the file. I have used this command, but it does not specify which column, but takes entire line,

```
grep -v '\s' file.txt |wc -l
```

Comment: Not quite sure hw to do using bash commands but in python: use a `set()` to keep track of all the ids. and use `len` on the result of `split` to count number of id's per line.

Comment: are you reading a file and there are multiple lines??

Comment: thank you @user2100799 I did it using set(), but was wondering if there are quicker ways to do it using bash commands

Comment: why is this even tagged python ... if you have no python and are not desiring a python answer?

Comment: number of columns vary from file to file, I am looking for unique ID's per column

Comment: @JoranBeasley I can untag python no problem for such a detail

Answer (score 0):

This awk should be more suitable:

```
awk 'NF>1{c++;next}
     NF==1{id=$1!=""?$1 :$2;a[id]++}
     END{
         print "both fields:"c
         for (i in a){print i,a[i]}}' infile
```

Comment: thank you, a bit of explanation for each line is very appreciated. Also, I need to print the sum of counts..

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to a python solution this seems to give what you are asking:

```
import re

reg = re.compile('\W+')
uniqueEntries = []
counts = dict()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as dataFile:
    for line in dataFile:
        result = re.split(reg, line)
        for item in result:
            if item is not '':
                if result.index(item) in counts:
                    counts[result.index(item)] += 1
                else:
                    counts[result.index(item)] = 1
                if item not in uniqueEntries:
                    uniqueEntries.append(item)
print('counts = {0}, uniqueEntries = {1}'.format(counts, uniqueEntries))
```

> > > counts = {0: 4, 1: 3}, uniqueEntries = ['Q8H1E4', 'C5XVC0', 'M7ZVB2', 'Q0J032', 'M0Z0D4', 'C4J6K5']